# game in oop mini game

Tags: object-oriented

So I am trying to create a small C# application which generates a deck of cards, and ask to the user if they want to shuffle the deck, and then display 1 card at a time to the user. Would this be effective use of classes 4 rules of oop? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment2OOP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call method to start the program
            DrawCards();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Short program which deals one card from deck at a time and also shuffles the deck
        private static void DrawCards()
        {
            Deck newDeck = new Deck();

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to shuffle your deck of cards? (type yes)");
            string option = Console.ReadLine();
            if(option == "yes" || option == "Yes")
            {
                newDeck.Shuffle();
                Console.Clear();
            }

            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to draw a card?" +
                                  "\n> Type 'yes' for yes\n> Type 'anything else' for no");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                
                if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "y")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine($"> {newDeck.Deal()}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No more cards will be drawn..");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Assignment2OOP
{
    class Card
    {
        // Fields 
        public List<string> Suit { get; private set; }
        public List<string> Value { get; private set; }

        // Constructor
        public Card()
        {
            Suit = new List<string> { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };
            Value = new List<string> { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                                       "Ace", "Queen", "Jack", "King"};
        }

        // Makes a set of unqiue cards
        public List<string> GetSetOfCards()
        {
            List<string> cardsSet = new List<string>();

            foreach (var suit in Suit) foreach (var value in Value) cardsSet.Add(value + " of " + suit);

            return cardsSet;
        }
    }
}
```

````
namespace Assignment2OOP
{
    class Deck
    {
        // Fields
        public List<string> cards { get; private set; }

        // Constructor 
        public Deck()
        {
            cards = new List<string>();
            FillDeck();
        }
        
        // Fill up the deck when a new object is instansiated
        private void FillDeck()
        {
            Card setOfCards = new Card();
            foreach(string card in setOfCards.GetSetOfCards()) cards.Add(card);
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {
            // Use Guid to shuffle the list
            //cards = cards.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

            // Or use more common way to shuffle
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int count = cards.Count;
            
            while(count > 1)
            {
                count--;
                int rng = rnd.Next(count);
                var value = cards[rng];
                cards[rng] = cards[count];
                cards[count] = value;
            }
        }

        // Keep an index of the top card of the deck
        private int topCardIndex = 51;
        public string Deal()
        {
            // Mark sure the deck isnt empty
            if(topCardIndex > 0)
            {
                // Get card at top and return it and decrease topCardIndex
                string topCard = cards[topCardIndex];
                topCardIndex--;
                return topCard;
            }
            else
            {
                return "No more cards left in the deck!";
            }
        }

        // Method which shows user all cards in current deck
        public void DisplayDeck()
        {
            foreach(var card in cards) Console.WriteLine(card);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: At the first glance I would say the abstractions and encapsulation are nailed. On the other hand it does support only one type of card set (French-suited cards). In case of OOP it might make sense to use inheritance and polymorphism to support different type of cards.

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for the feedback,yeh thats a good idea i will look to implement that.

Comment: I disagree with @PeterCsala that you nailed it.  `Card` is not really a card but a list of cards, which suggests it should be in `Deck`.  And `DisplayDeck` is a UI feature, so it should not be in `Deck`.

Comment: @RickDavin How would go about making the Cards class so that you can have a list of cards in the Deck class,as i struggled on that part.

Comment: @RickDavin Where would i put the DisplayDeck in a static method in main?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for quick review.  Work is pressing but rather than a conversation in comments, this will have to suffice.

There are lots of examples of C# and card games here at CR.  Maybe you could search for them and review since many of those answers are quite good.

The better answers use `enum` for `Suit` and `Rank`.  A `Card` class or struct is therefore a simple pairing of a `Suit` and `Rank`.  Granted later one must assign a value to a card based on rules of a particular game, e.g. is an Ace a value of 1 or 13 in Poker, or is it a 1 or 11 in BlackJack.

A `Deck` is a collection of cards.  I am not thrilled with names like `GetSetofCards` or `FillDeck`.  I am partial to `CreateStandardDeck`.

For the `Shuffle` method, the Fisher-Yates shuffle is the most highly recommended.  Typically it is wise to include a comment that you are using it just so any reviewer giving it a fast glance will see it.

One of the messiest non-OOP things I see in your code is mixing UI related things in with the logic.  `Deal` is returning a string.  To me, a deal should deal a hand, or else a set of hands to different players.  Maybe `GetNextCard` is a more appropriate name, or perhaps `GetTopCard`.  But that method should return a `Card`, not a string.  The UI is what displays a card, so move that logic back to what controls the console display.

Likewise `DisplayDeck` should be moved out of the `Deck` class and back to your UI class.  Except you really don't have a separate UI-related class other than the 2 methods in `Program`.  You may consider having a UI only class and move `DrawCards` into it, as well as these other UI methods I have touched upon.

I see a bit of repetition when asking for console input and checking an answer.  You may want to streamline this into a single method where you pass in a question and the acceptable answer.  If some answers are case sensitive, then you would also want to pass in a flag to ignore case so that "yes", "YES", and "Yes" are all the same good answer.

But again, my best advice is to search on [C#] and Card here on Code Review.  There is a wealth of information in some of those answers.

Comment: Thanks for the overall help, but some of the stuff you said was actually asked by the task - https://ibb.co/3hsTXVD Here is link the task image. And we also havent been taught to use enums at all,so iam trying to find a way to create the cards without enums,cause surely there must be away.

Comment: @Mj_ Do not take refuge in what being limited by what the task stated.  This will limit your progress as a developer.  Plus, you fall short of some of the directives about the task, e.g. that the `Card` needs to be a card and not a list of cards.

Comment: I updated the code would you say this is slighty better way?